# SVN Input / Output error

Tags: ubuntu, svn

I regularly take backups of Subversion. From past 4-5 days I have observed one of our project is giving input/output error while taking backup, Earlier also it has been crashed, I had restored it, From then on its working fine without any issues, The following are the error which I am getting while back-up.

> Dumping Subversion repo /svn/1452 to 1452_backup-20130325-0200...
> svnadmin: Can't write to stream: Input/output error
> Backing up through revision 6023...
>
> Compressing dump file...
>
> gzip: /mnt/Subversion/SVN-Backups/1452/1452_backup-20130325-0200.gz: Input/output error
>
> Created /mnt/Subversion/SVN-Backups/1452/1452_backup-20130325-0200.gz

Comment: Replace the failing hard drive.

Comment: Why? I have some more repos where I have doing this activity on shared folder on windows server. Other repos dont have any issues.
Does not seems to be relative.

Comment: Why replace a failing hard drive? That can't be a serious question?

Comment: But any other repos are not failing, only this repos is giving problem. Only when you run this backup script, it will show the error.
Thats why I asked.

Comment: Probably because it tries to write to 'bad' locations on the disk.  I hope you already replaced the drive by now.

Comment: No I did not replace the hdd. The problem was something else, While compressing using gzip the mem utilization was going high and it was failing. I replaced it with bzip2 now, its working fine. I got last 2 backups working fine. Observing for any errors if found.